# Is there any way to pass Observable<String> into AbstractInputStreamContent?

Tags: arrays, google-drive-api, rx-java, rx-java2, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm working on uploading a text file to Google Drive

```
ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent("text/csv", fileContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
Drive.Files.Insert request = drive.files().insert(file, content);
```

where `type(fileContent) = String`

I'd like to refactor and change type of `fileContent` to `Observable<String>`, is there any nice workaround to pass it to that `insert()` function (which takes `AbstractInputStreamContent` as a second argument)?

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably have to write a full, blocking adapter as `AbstractInputStreamContent` or look for one written with one of Google's own reactive API (gRPC, Agera, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general `Flowable` -> `InputStream` bridge you can delegate to:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.reactivestreams.*;

import io.reactivex.FlowableSubscriber;
import io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionHelper;

public final class FlowableStringInputStream {

    private FlowableStringInputStream() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No instances!");
    }

    public static InputStream createInputStream(
            Publisher<String> source, Charset charset) {
        StringInputStream parent = new StringInputStream(charset);
        source.subscribe(parent);
        return parent;
    }

    static final class StringInputStream extends InputStream
    implements FlowableSubscriber<String> {

        final AtomicReference<Subscription> upstream;

        final Charset charset;

        volatile byte[] bytes;

        int index;

        volatile boolean done;
        Throwable error;

        StringInputStream(Charset charset) {
            this.charset = charset;
            upstream = new AtomicReference<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            if (SubscriptionHelper.setOnce(upstream, s)) {
                s.request(1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String t) {
            bytes = t.getBytes(charset);
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            error = t;
            done = true;
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            done = true;
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            for (;;) {
                byte[] a = awaitBufferIfNecessary();
                if (a == null) {
                    Throwable ex = error;
                    if (ex != null) {
                        if (ex instanceof IOException) {
                            throw (IOException)ex;
                        }
                        throw new IOException(ex);
                    }
                    return -1;
                }
                int idx = index;
                if (idx == a.length) {
                    index = 0;
                    bytes = null;
                    upstream.get().request(1);
                } else {
                    int result = a[idx] & 0xFF;
                    index = idx + 1;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] awaitBufferIfNecessary() throws IOException {
            byte[] a = bytes;
            if (a == null) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    for (;;) {
                        boolean d = done;
                        a = bytes;
                        if (a != null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (d || upstream.get() == SubscriptionHelper.CANCELLED) {
                            break;
                        }
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            if (upstream.get() != SubscriptionHelper.CANCELLED) {
                                InterruptedIOException exc = new InterruptedIOException();
                                exc.initCause(ex);
                                throw exc;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            return a;
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            if (off < 0 || len < 0 || off >= b.length || off + len > b.length) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "b.length=" + b.length + ", off=" + off + ", len=" + len);
            }
            for (;;) {
                byte[] a = awaitBufferIfNecessary();
                if (a == null) {
                    Throwable ex = error;
                    if (ex != null) {
                        if (ex instanceof IOException) {
                            throw (IOException)ex;
                        }
                        throw new IOException(ex);
                    }
                    return -1;
                }
                int idx = index;
                if (idx == a.length) {
                    index = 0;
                    bytes = null;
                    upstream.get().request(1);
                } else {
                    int r = 0;
                    while (idx < a.length && len > 0) {
                        b[off] = a[idx];
                        idx++;
                        off++;
                        r++;
                        len--;
                    }
                    index = idx;
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            byte[] a = bytes;
            int idx = index;
            return a != null ? Math.max(0, a.length - idx) : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            SubscriptionHelper.cancel(upstream);
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
@Test(timeout = 10000)
public void async() throws Exception {
    AtomicInteger calls = new AtomicInteger();

    Flowable<String> f = Flowable.range(100, 10).map(Object::toString)
            .doOnCancel(() -> calls.incrementAndGet())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .delay(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    try (InputStream is = FlowableStringInputStream.createInputStream(f, utf8)) {
        assertEquals('1', is.read());
        assertEquals('0', is.read());
        assertEquals('0', is.read());

        byte[] buf = new byte[3];
        assertEquals(3, is.read(buf));

        assertArrayEquals("101".getBytes(utf8), buf);
    }

    assertEquals(1, calls.get());
}
```

Comment: Looks great, could you help me integrating this code (I didn't get a part about delegating)?
I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work, cause `insert()` requires `AbstractInputStreamContent` as a 2nd argument.
`InputStream in = FlowableStringInputStream.createInputStream(Flowable.just(""), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            Drive.Files.Insert req = drive.files().insert(file, in);`

Comment: Create an instance of `AbstractInputStreamContent` and delegate to the respective method of `in`.

Comment: Thanks, so basically there're 3 methods: `getInputStream()` should return this instance that I've created previously (`InputStream inputStream = FlowableStringInputStream.createInputStream(textFlowable, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`, `retrySupported -> false`, how do I provide implementation for `getLength` in a nice Rx fashion? I haven't found a corresponding method in `FlowableStringInputStream`.

Updated a question.

Comment: Because flows are generally unknown length so you can't tell it upfront unless you are willing to buffer all of the data, convert it upfront and get its length. Also you are allowed to not know it: [getLength()](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpContent#getLength()).